# How to access the UIImagePickerController Shutter UiButton from Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer, ios-camera

i would like to access to the Shutter UiButton from a xamarin.iOS App 
so i can do some changes on it, but i'm not able to find it.

so i tried to recreate the UIImagePickerController project in xcode, and i  i found it using this code and i'm able to do the changes.
does xamarin.iOS have a different view hierarchy ?

```
 for (index,v) in self.imagePicker.view.subviews.enumerated()
                    {
                        print("layer \(index) : \(v)")
                        for (index2,vv) in v.subviews.enumerated()
                        {
                            print("layer \(index, index2) : \(vv)")

                            for (index3,vvv) in vv.subviews.enumerated()
                            {
                                print("layer \(index, index2, index3) : \(vvv)")

                                for (index4,vvvv) in vvv.subviews.enumerated()
                                {
                                    print("layer \(index, index2, index3, index4) : \(vvvv)")
                                    for (index5,vvvvv) in vvvv.subviews.enumerated()
                                    {
                                        print("layer \(index, index2, index3, index4, index5) : \(vvvvv)")

                                        for (index6,vvvvvv) in vvvvv.subviews.enumerated()
                                        {
                                            print("layer \(index, index2, index3, index4, index5, index6) : \(vvvvvv)")

                                            if (vvvvvv as? UIButton != nil)
                                            {
                                                var t =  String(describing:type(of:vvvvvv))
                                                if(t == "CUShutterButton")
                                                {
                                                    print("is button CUShutterButton")
                                                    (vvvvvv as! UIButton).setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
                                                     (vvvvvv as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                                    v.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
                                                    for (vvvvvvv) in vvvvvv.subviews
                                                    {
                                                          vvvvvvv.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

[Image : can't find the UiButton from vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9cv.jpg)

Comment: Could you show C# code or image,I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin doesn't have a different view hierarchy. Your problem is in those lines:

```
                                                var t =  String(describing:type(of:vvvvvv))
                                            if(t == "CUShutterButton")
```

I am not sure how you have translated this to Xamarin (which may influence the results too), but the string description of the type of the class can be different. So you need to list all strings, find the right one and use it in your if statement.

Comment: i haven't translated this in that way, i tried to debug my xamarin.iOS code and searched the button inside the UiimagePickerController instance from visual studio